# RecycleView doesn't show all the information

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, calendar

I have an `RecycleView` and it which shows the events that will happen in future and it worked fine (all the information showed up) but after that i added 2 more buttons to the layout after running it i had fewer events and i don't know why(i didn't change any code in the java file)

here is my code:

```
    private void setupAdaptaterNew() {
    mPostAdapterNew = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.item_layout_evenimente,
            PostViewHolder.class,
            mPostRef
    ) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position) {
            final int EndOra = viewHolder.setEndOra(model.getEndOra());
            final long EndZi = viewHolder.setEndZi(model.getEndZi());
            final int EndLuna = viewHolder.setEndLuna(model.getEndLuna());
            final int EndAn = viewHolder.setEndAn(model.getEndAn());

            final ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            final ContentResolver crReminder = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            final ContentValues[] valuesReminder = {new ContentValues()};
            final Uri[] event = new Uri[1];


            final String headline = viewHolder.setHeadline(model.getHeadline());
            final String locatie = viewHolder.setStrada(model.getStrada());
            final String organizator = viewHolder.setOrganizator(model.getOrganizator());

            final Button btnDeleteEvent = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.BtnNuParticip);
            final Button btnAddEvent = viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.BtnParticip);

            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, EndOra);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, EndLuna);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (int) EndZi);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, EndAn);


            if (Calendar.getInstance().before(cal)) {
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(model.getImageUrl());
                Glide.with(Evenimente.this)
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(storageReference)
                        .into(viewHolder.postIV);

                viewHolder.setHeadline(model.getHeadline());
                viewHolder.setZiua(model.getZiua());
                viewHolder.setLuna(model.getLuna());
                viewHolder.setOra(model.getOra());
                viewHolder.setOrganizator(model.getOrganizator());
                viewHolder.setCategoria(model.getCategoria());
                viewHolder.setStrada(model.getStrada());
                viewHolder.setLocalitatea(model.getLocalitatea());
                viewHolder.setPostDescriere(model.getDescriere());
            } else {
                viewHolder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            }
            btnAddEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permisii insuficiente.\n Va rugam sa activati permisiunea de CALENDAR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        long startMillis = 0;
                        long endMillis = 0;

                        //Start and End of event date

                        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        beginTime.set(EndAn, EndLuna, (int) EndZi, EndOra, 0);
                        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
                        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        endTime.set(EndAn, EndLuna, (int) EndZi, EndOra, 0);
                        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

                        //Add Values
                        values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
                        values.put(Events.TITLE, headline);
                        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Description"); //TODO change description here!
                        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
                        values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
                        values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
                        values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
                        values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, locatie);
                        values.put(Events.ORGANIZER, organizator);
                        event[0] = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
                        valuesReminder[0].put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DTSTART, startMillis);
                        Uri REMINDERS_URI_DAY = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "reminders");
                        valuesReminder[0] = new ContentValues();
                        valuesReminder[0].put("event_id", Long.parseLong(event[0].getLastPathSegment()));
                        valuesReminder[0].put("method", 1);
                        valuesReminder[0].put("minutes", 1440);
                        Uri uriReminderDay = crReminder.insert(REMINDERS_URI_DAY, valuesReminder[0]);
                        Uri REMINDERS_URI_HOUR = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(true) + "reminders");
                        valuesReminder[0] = new ContentValues();
                        valuesReminder[0].put("event_id", position);
                        valuesReminder[0].put("method", 1);
                        valuesReminder[0].put("minutes", 120);
                        Uri uriReminder = crReminder.insert(REMINDERS_URI_HOUR, valuesReminder[0]);
                        createDialogAddEvent(headline);


                        btnDeleteEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnAddEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }
            });
            btnDeleteEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Uri deleteUri = null;
                    deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(event[0].getLastPathSegment()));
                    int rows = getContentResolver().delete(deleteUri, null, null);

                    btnDeleteEvent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnAddEvent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //Create Dialog;
                    createDialogDeleteEvent(headline);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

private String getCalendarUriBase(boolean eventUri) {
    Uri calendarURI = null;
    try {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
            calendarURI = (eventUri) ? Uri.parse("content://calendar/") : Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
        } else {
            calendarURI = (eventUri) ? Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/") : Uri
                    .parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return calendarURI.toString();
}
```

And this is my RecycleView model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!--Adding padding to the image view makes it easy to click -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_ziua"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_luna"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="IAN"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:text="---------"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_ora"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10:00"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_iv"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headline_event"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Numele complet al evenimentului"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
                        android:layout_width="14dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        app:srcCompat="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView60"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Categoria:"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_categoria"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Categoria"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
                        android:layout_width="14dp"
                        android:layout_height="14dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="1.5dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_people_black_24px" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_organizator"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Organizator:"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_strada"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Strada:"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_localitatea"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Localitatea"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DescriereEveniment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnParticip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Particip!"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnNuParticip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nu m-ai particip"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

So can you guys tell me why some values didn't show up after adding the buttons whit id: BtnParticip/BtnNuParticipt at the end of the xml file

Comment: you mean you only added parts to the xml? please tell me which part exactly you added

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnParticip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Particip!"
        /> 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnNuParticip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nu m-ai particip"
        /> This part and i added only to the xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the **height** of inner `LinearLayout` to `match_parent` which is using all the space and buttons are not showing up.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // Change it to wrap_content
        android:orientation="vertical">

       ....

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DescriereEveniment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnParticip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Particip!"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnNuParticip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nu m-ai particip"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: It's not that the buttons doesn't show up :) they do but after adding the buttons i lost 2 of my items

Comment: @LuisFernandoScripcaru Can you put the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Close The CardView, you have opened a CardView at the top of the xml file but did not close it.

Add this to the End of the file

```
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: please tell me how did it go

Comment: I have the closing tag i didn't copy it in the code above and if i didn't had it the editor would tell me this :D

Comment: Edit: no :( sorry the last comm was not for this issue :(